# Replacing items in a list in all possible permutations

Tags: python, list, permutation

Let's say I have a list or an array of the type:

```
mylist = [1, 2, 3, 4]
```

And I want to replace an item in this list. Normally I would use something like the following:

```
mylist[2] = 7
```

That works well. However, can someone explain how to create all possible permutations of `mylist` when replacing one or more items in `mylist`. For example, I want to create the following:

```
[7, 2, 3, 4]
[7, 7, 3, 4]
[7, 2, 7, 4]
[7, 7, 7, 4]
[7, 2, 3, 7]
...(and so on)
```

I know I can use `itertools` to generate all possible permutations, but how can I specify that I want to substitute an item in all possible locations in the list before generating the permutations? Here is how I tried to use `itertools`:

```
list(itertools.permutations([1,2,3,4,7], 4))
```

This doesn't work because it doesn't substitute `7` more than one time per permutation, and it also generates permutations that do not include the number `7`.

Comment: Your example seems to say that you want to replace at least one item in your list with the value (`7` in your example) while leaving the un-replaced items in place. Is that what you mean? So in your example there would be 15 lists in the result?

Comment: I don't understand how you get two or three sevens in some of your result lists.

Comment: This question was a hard one to explain.  I'm looking to substitute in all possible locations, thus the list of permutations are generated.  I tried to explain it this way because I was focused on using itertools.permutations to solve this.  Perhaps that wasn't the correct wording.

Comment: I suppose the order is important. E.g.: output record`[7, 2, 3, 7]`, it is fine, but `[2, 3, 7, 7]` is not, making `permutations` not suitable.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use `itertools.combinations` to find the indices to replace:

```
replace = 7
mylist = [1, 2, 3, 4]
for i in range(1, len(mylist) + 1):
    for selected in itertools.combinations(range(len(mylist)), i):
        res = mylist[:]
        for n in selected:
            res[n] = replace
        print(res)
```

Output:

```
[7, 2, 3, 4]
[1, 7, 3, 4]
[1, 2, 7, 4]
[1, 2, 3, 7]
[7, 7, 3, 4]
[7, 2, 7, 4]
[7, 2, 3, 7]
[1, 7, 7, 4]
[1, 7, 3, 7]
[1, 2, 7, 7]
[7, 7, 7, 4]
[7, 7, 3, 7]
[7, 2, 7, 7]
[1, 7, 7, 7]
[7, 7, 7, 7]
```

Comment: That's it!  Interesting use of itertools.combinations.  Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You can create a function and just pass the list and value to that function and you get what you want :

```
import itertools
def replaced_it(list_1,value):

    final_list = []
    len_=len(list_1)
    track_index = [k for k, j in enumerate(list_1)]
    for i in range(len(track_index) + 1):


        empty_list = [value]
        replaced_one = list_1[:]
        for ia in itertools.permutations(track_index, r=i):
            if ia:
                for i, j in zip(ia, empty_list * len(ia)):
                    replaced_one[i] = j
                if replaced_one not in final_list:
                    final_list.append(replaced_one)
                replaced_one = list_1[:]






    return final_list

print(replaced_it([1,2,3,4],7))
```

output:

```
[[7, 2, 3, 4], [1, 7, 3, 4], [1, 2, 7, 4], [1, 2, 3, 7], [7, 7, 3, 4], [7, 2, 7, 4], [7, 2, 3, 7], [1, 7, 7, 4], [1, 7, 3, 7], [1, 2, 7, 7], [7, 7, 7, 4], [7, 7, 3, 7], [7, 2, 7, 7], [1, 7, 7, 7], [7, 7, 7, 7]]
```